# MOV Instruction for Registers

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu-registers, mov

So I am running _asm with C++ using Visual Studio.

So I am new to assembly programming, I am following a textbook and know that the general register EAX holds 32 bits and AX is 16 with AL, AH being low/high.

So how would I move multiple commands using only the MOV instruction. I tried doing

```
MOV AL, 'a', 'c' , 'e'
```

but I get illegal amount of operands. Thats only 3 so shouldn't AL be able to hold that value?

I tried after doing

```
MOV EAX, 0
MOV AL, 'a', 'c' , 'e'
```

So how would I move three different values or even more like 12 letters to 8 bit? Shouldn't me moving 0 to eax clear out both the low and high of the 8 bit allowing those 3 variables to be moved?? I only want to use 8-bit register to move multiple values into it, in this case which is 3. Also I like to know how to do more like 12 letters into 8 Bit. I read you would make MOV EAX, 0 but I had no luck.

Note: This isn't the full program, I only included the problem with MOV.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;


int main(void)
{

    char test
    _asm
    {
        MOV EAX, 0
        MOV AL, 'a', 'c' , 'e'
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `mov eax, 'ace'`?

Comment: Inline asm isn't the best choice for learning asm, IMO.  There are some suggestions in the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info tag wiki.  `mov` can't take multiple source operands.  You can get the assembler to do math to produce a value for an immediate source operand, but the syntax looks like `mov eax, ( 'a' << 16 | 'c' << 8 | 'e' )`.  (Or something like that).  Note that it's a single expression that has an integer value.  And how do you think 12 letters can fit in 8 bits anyway?  An ASCII char is 8 bits.

Comment: So moving 0 to EAX would only allow you to max insert 8 letters into the 8 bit register (hi & low). I understand that now, I thought for some reason there was a way to do so.  Thanks for your help, I also though mov has multiple operands,

Comment: `mov eax, 0` does *nothing* useful.  To put 4 letters into eax, you need another 4-byte immediate mov, which overwrites the zeros.  A letter takes a whole byte, not a bit.  Go look at some of the links in the x86 tag wiki.  You clearly have some wrong ideas about how things work, and reading some stuff will probably clear things up.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to place in _EAX_, but Mr. Oblivious suggestion would be reasonable if you are trying to get the MASM assembler to build a 4 byte string and encode it for storage in a 32-bit register. `mov eax, 'ace\0'`  would generate an immediate (constant value of) 0x61636500 and store it in _EAX_.If you were to store that in memory on an x86 machine though the bytes would appear in reverse order (x86 is little endian). This seems like a potential XY problem though.

Comment: A part of me thinks that you are really looking to use a pointer to memory containing a string and setting the characters.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I didn't know about that syntax for expressions, so I tried it out:  With YASM and NASM, `mov eax, 'abc\0'` warns that the value doesn't fit in 32bits.  It doesn't process backslash-escapes, so you get `b8 61 62 63 5c`              `mov    eax,0x5c636261` (i.e. a literal backslash as the MSB).  Is this another difference between the NASM and MASM languages?

Comment: Yes, this is syntax that MASM has supported for decades and is a difference between compilers.

Comment: Since it is unclear how he wants the bytes stuffed in _EAX_, to get 0x61636500 in _EAX_ you can use `mov eax, 'ace\0'` . If you want the MSB to be zero (0x00616365 )instead you can use `mov eax, 'ace'` which was originally suggested by Mr Oblivious

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, this is syntax that MASM has supported for decades and is a difference between assemblers (MASM compatible assemblers vs others)

Comment: @PeterCordes Since _MASM_ syntax is part of Visual Studio C++, I've provided this example code to demonstrate the _MASM_ syntax via inline assembler. Same thing applies to pure _MASM_: http://rextester.com/edit/JXH99489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you only got literals to push up into EAX you can use the following code:

```
MOV EAX, 'ace'
```

If you want a piece of code that can use three variables to compose the value that goes on EAX, use the following code as a template and replace literals with variable names.

```
MOV EAX, 'a' * 0x10000 + 'c' * 0x100 + 'e'
```

And finally if you'd like a solution that pushes a character by character you can use the following:

```
void init()
{
    _asm
    {
       XOR EAX, EAX
    }
}

void push(char c)
{
    _asm
    {
        SHL EAX, 8
        MOV AL, c
    }
}
```

> Also I like to know how to do more like 12 letters into 8 Bit. I read
>   you would make MOV EAX, 0 but I had no luck.

I cannot get what you mean by this, do you mean 12 characters inside EAX. EAX is 32-bit which means only 4 ASCII characters. But if what you were trying to fit into EAX are hex digits (0-9 and a-f) this means you can fit 8 of these into EAX no more.

Comment: That needs to be `shl eax, 8` to shift by a whole byte.  Are you getting mixed up between `'a'` (0x61) and `0xa`?  Even so, you'd want `xor eax, eax` / `mov al, 0xa` / `shl al, 4` / `or eax, 0xc` / `shl eax, 4` / `or eax, 0xe`.  (This should avoid any partial-register slowdowns on Intel CPUs.  Your sequence has a partial-reg stall or merging uop on pre-IvB hardware on the 2nd `shl`, because the first `shl` removes upper-bits-clear tag by writing the full register with something other than a zeroing idiom)

Comment: Your `mov eax, imm32` first version has the same problem: try `'a' * 0x10000 + 'c' * 0x100 + 'e'`.  Each ASCII character takes a whole byte (two hex digits, aka nibbles)

Comment: Thanks Peter, totally missed that, for some reason assumed it is a hex digit not a whole character. My answer is fixed accordingly.

Comment: First I didn't know that 'ace' is equivalent to ('a' << 16) + ('c' << 8) + 'e'. So thanks for that :)

Second, I am not sure if OP wanted a zero terminated string, so may be `MOV EAX, 'ace'` would be what he/she is after.

Comment: @Michael, I read your comment on the OP, if you are trying to make EAX point to the literal string "ace" this is a different thing and 'ace\0' is not the same. Probably something you already know but I am just making sure.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question asking for a 0 in the lowest byte. The only reason I can think of why separating the values is in case they are not literal in the final solution which is hinted in the OP question